# Animate view and set button backgroundimage conflict

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiviewanimation, drawer

I am making a type of drawer animation for iOS where a button tap in one of my views will expand that view over the other views from the bottom up. All is well, except when I want to change the button image after animation. The animation completes but then returns the view to its original position when setting the button image.

Things I have tried:

- Using CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation instead of setCenter; this works perfectly, except I want to also add a panGestureRecognizer to interact with the drawer, present, and dismiss it. The transform doesn't seem to play well with this interaction
- Adding the buttons programmatically thinking maybe AutoLayout is fussing with this
- UIView beginAnimations as well as UIView animateWithDuration and completion block
- Setting breakpoints and verifying that the movement of the view is reflected in the frame of the button before the image is changed; button frame is not still in original position, but has supposedly relocated with the view

It shouldn't matter, but my project is using TabBarController. I made a simpler version of what I'm trying to do with just the one view controller and had the same issue. The green view extends beyond the frame of the view controller's view so that when it moves up it reveals what is off-screen.
example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGJgZ.png

Comment: Issue: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2ezmjuv%3E&s=8#.Vdj47dNViko
Desired effect: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=9u41w2%3E&s=8#.Vdj5J9NViko

Comment: Might help if you show or give some indication on how you are animating the view. Also are you using auto layout constraints in ay of the views / subviews?

Comment: The example image link has my animation code in it. I've got a hack working right now where I just made two buttons on top of each other with the two images. Then I just use the Hidden property of the button to show or hide the correct image-button. This allows me to use setCenter in animation rather than any CGAffineTransform, which plays better with my pan gesture